# groupby shapely type in geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, geospatial, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe with a geom field that retains heterogeneous shapely data types.
I want to group them by type (e.g. shapely.geometry.Point, shapely.geometry.Polygon, shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon, etc.). This task would be accomplished via something like this:

```
main_gdf_clean['geometry'].groupby(by=shapely.geometry.Point)
```

Is there a workable way to accomplish what I am describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `GeoSeries.geom_type`

groupby the geometry type (`df['geometry'].geom_type`) instead of the actual geometry.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

df  = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                     Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)]),
                     Point(1,2), Point(2,3), Point(3,3)]).to_frame('geometry')
df = df.set_geometry(col='geometry')  # So this example knows geometry

# Broadcast # of elements per unique shape type
df['N_items'] = df.groupby(df['geometry'].geom_type).transform('count')
#                                            geometry  N_items
#0  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 3.00000 1.00000, 3....        2
#1  POLYGON ((3.00000 3.00000, 5.00000 3.00000, 5....        2
#2                            POINT (1.00000 2.00000)        3
#3                            POINT (2.00000 3.00000)        3
#4                            POINT (3.00000 3.00000)        3
```